# How to Iterate through subdirectories with same name in a path?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a bash script that is iterating through sub directories where parts of the path are identical. Maybe best is to show an example:

Directories:

- /path/same/
- /path2/same/
- /path3/same/

Then I want to "do something" to all files contained in those directories and save them in another of those sub directories.

Results:

- /path/another/
- /path2/another/
- /path3/another/

I guess it has to be done with some kind of

```
for i in /*/same/* ; do
    ... do something with $i ...
done
```

loop, but somehow all I try ends up not returning anything in $i.

any tips? thanks :)

Comment: `for i in /*/same/*; do` searches only for directories two levels from the system root (`/var/same`, `/home/same` etc) - you probably want `*/same/*` or `./*/same/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code looks good to me. How many files do you have in these directories? There is a limit for wildcard expansion. In this case you should use `find`, for example like that:

```
find /path*/same | while read i ; do echo "do something with file: $i" ; done
```